# There is a Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CON = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Transport.accdb")
        COM = New OleDbCommand(" Update details DName=@DName,Address=@Address,DOB=@DOB,MoNo=@MoNo,LiNo=@LiNo,LiExNo=@LiExNo,Experiance=@Experiance,Note=@Note where DNo=@DNo", CON)

        CON.Open()
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DNo", TextBox9.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DName", TextBox8.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox1.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", TextBox2.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoNo", TextBox3.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LiNo", TextBox4.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LiExNo", TextBox5.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Experiance", TextBox6.Text)
        COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", TextBox7.Text)

        COM.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("record Updated")
        CON.Close()
```

Comment: you missed `SET` in the command

Answer (score 1):

You missed the SET keyword

```
Update details SET DName=@DName
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not written `set` keyword in update statement.

```
COM = New OleDbCommand(" Update details set DName=@DName,Address=@Address,DOB=@DOB,MoNo=@MoNo,LiNo=@LiNo,LiExNo=@LiExNo,Experiance=@Experiance,Note=@Note where DNo=@DNo", CON)
```